# Динамическое удаление строк таблицы

Tags: html, ajax

Есть вот такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В столбце "Delete/Change", при нажатии на красную иконку формируется ajax-запрос, в котором передается id строки.id записан в сlass иконки.Как реализовать удаление строки, ajax-запрос которой был передан.
Или реализовать чекбоксы для выбора записей, а по нажатию кнопки отправлять массив id, с последующем обновлением таблицы?

Comment: Если вам не нужно при этом подгружать новую строку вместо удалённой (например, если на странице 10 первых товаров, то после удаления 4го 11й становится 10м, и его было бы логично подгрузить. И то - только его, а не все 10), то тогда смысла грузить всё заново вообще нет. По поводу _"как удалить строку_ - нужен HTML-код таблицы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации нам вовсе не обязательно знать класс или идентификатор ряда. Нам достаточно обратиться к ряду относительно самой кнопки удаления.

Пример на **jQuery** ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytv7dpv9/1/)):

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Первый ряд</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="row-remove">Удалить</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Второй ряд</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="row-remove">Удалить</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.row-remove').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('tr').remove(); // или $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Документация jQuery для [`.closest()`](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/closest/) и [`.parent()`](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/parent/)

Comment: 1. `.parent().parent()` - хрупкая штука, `.closest('tr')` всё же лучше в качестве основного варианта ответа. 2. Имеет смысл код `$('.row-remove').click( ... );` обернуть в `document.ready`, чтобы у автора не было проблем при добавлении этого скрипта в `<head>`.

Comment: @Regent Чтобы у автора не было проблем при добавлении скрипта в `<head>`, автор должен понимать как выполняется js на странице, а это уже выходит за рамки вопроса. Ответ все-же подправил :)

Comment: Да автор, видимо, вообще забыл про вопрос... Остаётся лишь плюсовать ответы. Один момент по поводу нового кода: он несколько избыточен. Хватило бы `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });`, без анонимной функции.

Comment: я решил использовать двойное обращение к родителю+ремув.сам нашел такое-а тут тоже самое предлагают,спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [`jQuery.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) для поиска **ближайшего** к кликнутому элемента `<tr>` ([фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/wnt8oou6/)):

```
$('tr i.glyphicon-remove').on('click', function(e){
    $(e.target).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: А почему вы взяли `e.target`, а не `this`?

Comment: @Regent Не задумываясь, по (вредной) привычке. Какие могут быть проблемы?

Comment: В данном случае - никаких. Код честно работает и так, и так. Просто заинтересовала причина его использования, потому что используется и реже (с jQuery), и длиннее (по символам). И плохо что автор так и не предоставил HTML-код - нет уверенности в том, что можно спокойно плюсовать ответы, не говоря уж о размещении своего ответа.

Comment: Риск, что между кнопкой и строкой есть ещё одна вложенная таблица со строкой ≈ 1E-11 : )

Причина `e.target` – часто там же добавляю `e.preventDefault();`. Работаю с событием, чтобы не плодить сущностей )

Comment: Почему же сразу `≈ 1E-11`? :) Достаточно написать код несколько нехорошо, и проблема появится: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/wnt8oou6/1/). Если в этом коде `this` заменить на `e.target`, то работать будет неправильно. Это я лишь к тому, что главное - помнить разницу между ними.

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю как с  работают атрибуты , но можно попробовать.
 Назначаете строке идентификатор и унопке удаления на той же строке атрибут с идентификатором строки. 
1. Кликаем на крестик 
2. Получаем атрибут крестика с идентификатором строки 
3. Удаляем строку с идентификатором

типо

```
<tr class="myRow1">
    <td>Удалить эту строку</td><td><img src="крестик" delRow="myRow1" ></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: А где код этих пунктов _1-2-3_? И всё же достаточно сложно угадать как именно выглядит таблица автора.